# error insert date mysql vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, insert

I have the column named breakdown date in my database. it's type is "Date"
when i'm inserting into my database a breakdown i have a problem with the date column

```
Private Sub BT_SAVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_SAVE.Click

    Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO Pannes VALUES(03082016,'" & CB_AV.SelectedItem.ToString() & "','" & TXT_PAN.Text & "','" & TXT_DET.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd") & "')"
    SavePann(SQLStatement)
End Sub
```

i get the error 
Incorrect date value: '2016-47-16' for column 'DATE' at row 1
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your month is incorrect. '2016-47-16'.  I suspect it's a minute value.

Use `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` instead.

Comment: Thank you mr @FloatingKiwi it works now. i have another question :when i generate a pdf containing all breakdowns the date i get is like this 12/08/2016 00:00:00 : i want to get ride of hours and minutes and seconds and show only short date  here is my code for column's date ` dataRow(DGV_SIT.Columns(4).HeaderText.ToString()) = DGV_SIT.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value`

Comment: I'm not familiar with PDF generation. I'd suggest posting as a new question with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [SQL parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) instead of concat a big Insert string. This will avoid such errors like you describe.

Also you don´t have to convert a `Date` parameter into a String when MySql is translating it back to a `Date` value anyways. Just use the `DateTimePicker.Value`.

```
 Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO Pannes VALUES(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5)"
```

(I suggest to replace the parameter names with meaningful ones).

And in `SavePann` make use of `Using` since it automatically disposes your connection and command objects.

```
Using conn as New MySqlConnection
   conn.ConnectionString = "YourSqlConnectionString"
   conn.Open()
   Using cmd as New MySqlCommand 
       cmd.Connection = conn
       cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement
       cmd.Prepare()

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 03082016)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", CB_AV.SelectedItem.ToString())
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", TXT_PAN.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", TXT_DET.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", DateTimePicker1.Value) 'No ToString needed'

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
End Using
```